# sql datetime. how to set the month

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
DECLARE @DateMin AS datetime = '2019-01-05 00:00:00';
DECLARE @PrmMois AS tinyint = 4;
```

How do I replace the month by 04 ?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: use DATEFROMPARTS()

Comment: So why post a duplicate question? If you can do it for a year, why can't you do it for a month?

Comment: Why are you commenting with answers to your own question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are simply looking for replace January with April in your variable, you can use DATEADD method for that as below-

```
SET @DateMin = DATEADD(MM,3,@DateMin)
```

If you wants this for any date belongs to any month to be replaced by April, do this below-

```
SET @DateMin = DATEADD(MM,-MONTH(@DateMin)+4,@DateMin)
```